# Reactjs - Web app need runtime permission?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, permissions

I'm working currently on a web audio recorder with `getUsermedia` on `Reactjs`.

My app works great on browsers.

On some mobile devices the `microphone` permission is systematically denied even after going in the parameter and activating the microphone. So before diving in the subject, I would share my wonder about the fact that, on web app does a runtime permission is necessary ? especially for Android devices ?

Also I have seen that microphone permission is considered as a `dangerous permission`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **YES**. You must need to show runtime permission popup for mobile applications. It does not matter whether that app is native application or hybrid application.

**You can not skip/ignore/hide run time permission** if you users to install your app on their smartphones.

Comment: Thanks VicJordan for your answer. Okay, I have an another question please, an hybrid app can be a full Reactjs app, not necessary a Cordova or Phone Gap app that it ? In my case users doesn't install the app in their smartphones, just reach the website and click on "record". But I assume you mean "runtime permission every time their is an install, and runtime permission only when some feature accessing if it is a web app case " if I understand you well

Comment: Any cross-platform application is a hybrid app. Yes correct full reactjs app can be a hybrid app.